# Why can't we make circular dependencies in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, circular-dependency

In Ionic I made 2 services to provide datas

```
export class DocumentService {

  constructor(favorisService: FavorisService) { }

  async GetById(id: number): Promise<DocumentModel>{
    let path = this.favorisService.getPath();
    // Get document's additionnal datas from BDD
    // Gets back document depending on path
  }

  async GetById(id: number): Promise<DocumentModel>{
     //request server and sends back a document
  }
}

export class FavorisService {

  constructor(httpServer: httpServerService) { }

  async Synchronize(id: number): Promise<FavorisModel>{
     //if favoris was never synchronized, get document on server
     //then downloads document with document.getDocument
  }

  GetPathToDocument(){//returns favoris's document's path}
}
```

I don't understand why I can't import favorisService in documentService AND documentService in favorisService, the purpose to service is to provide datas, why can't they provide datas to each other ?

I made a third service called FavorisDocumentService

```
export class FavorisDocumentService{

  constructor(
    httpServer: httpServerService, favorisService: FavorisService,
    documentService: DocumentService
  ) { }

  async GetById(id: number): Promise<FavorisModel>{
    this.favoris = await this.favorisService.getById(id);
    this.favoris.document = await this.documentService.getById(id);
  }
}
```

the problem is not it doesn't work (actually it works), the problem is I have to make another service for each combination or objects. I made this because my project was smaller and I had only 2 relations that forced me to create a third service, but now I have to make "DocumentFavorisUserServices" and others... (well with my example you could say I just put documentService in favorisService but sometimes I need favorisService in documentService)

What is the purpose of not allow to do "circular dependencies" and what would be the right way to do it ?
(I work with Ionic 4)

EDIT ----

A favoris can contain a document, but a document is not always linked to a favoris, and this document, depending on the favoris, can be stocked in different places, depending on how the favoris managed it. So the "path" data is inside favoris and not in document. that's why sometimes I need favoris in document, because when I have my "getdocument" (which i put in documentservice), I need the path to that document (to get it back). The single responsibility principle in this case is kind of blurr on which object has which responsibility (I made an edit to my objects example)

Comment: Actually I don't understand why I would "create" anything, the providers are ukind of always the same, if you edit it somewhere it will keep datas,  and when you provide it you provide an already existing object

Comment: Yes, this would be an Angular issue, not specifically ionic. And re: your question: Circular dependencies can cause a domino effect when a small local change in one module spreads into other modules and has unwanted global effects (program errors, compile errors). Circular dependencies can also result in infinite recursions or other unexpected failures.

Comment: @AmaniteLaurine Angular needs to create instances of your services. So it has to call their constructors, and pass the arguments they need. So it needs to create a FavorisService, and pass it a DocumentService. So it needs to create a DocumentService, and pass it a FavorisService.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not going about it the right way. A `FavorisService` should only obtain 'favoris', and a `DocumentService` should only be busy with documents. That these objects have keys to each other, should not change that. If you need data from both in your component, you should query from both services. If you tend to do this pattern alot, you make a wrapper service to do this for you (like you did)

Try to keep your services have only one responsibility and/or restructure your data object structures that there are no circular references.

The reason that circular dependencies are not allowed in Ionic, is because this is not allowed in ES5.

> The more references you make inside your code, the harder it is to test and more complicated to understand — you end up with spaghetti code. Additionally, many references create circular dependencies, which cause bugs directly.

In ES6 this is sorta solved, but I believe you should never have circular dependencies (see quote above here).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I made an edit to my post to add more precisions about my case, the responsabilities are kind of blur about which object should have which responsabilities